# How can I separate my GUI code from my functionality into 2 Rkt files?

Tags: user-interface, scheme, lisp, racket

I have a large program that has calls between functions that modify object state, and object instances that call functions.

Right now, they are all in one .rkt file. Some of the functions reference objects to update their contents, and some of the objects reference functions in their callback field. Is there a way to separate functions from the GUI code?

Comment: Are you looking for advice on how to use Racket's module system, or advice on how to structure programs in general?  I think the latter is a big subject!

Comment: The second...but it probably involves the first. Yeah I guess I just should keep trying until I figure it out on my own. For some reason, callbacks to functions that are defined after the object definition were throwing errors (I think), but they are not throwing errors now, so all my object definitions are grouped above the function section.

Comment: OK, I can add an answer with a fairly simple-minded (all I understand) guide to modules & contracts in a little while, in case that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, there are two parts to this question:

- the first is how do you structure programs with GUI components, or in general;
- the second is how can Racket help you with the first.

I think the first part is an enormous topic: books have been written about this, and courses taught.  I'm definitely not up to answering that part.

The second part, well, I'm also not really up to answering that in general either as I'm not really a Racket expert.  But, as no-one else has, perhaps I can help for the simple cases (and most cases, I think, turn out to be simple).

Warning: what follows is *certainly* oversimplified and *almost certainly* contains errors.  I would welcome correction from anyone who knows the Racket module system better than me.  It's also got too long for an answer which was meant to be simple: sorry.

### Modules in Racket

The basic thing to realise is that everything you write in Racket is part of the definition of a module, (the whole `#lang ...` thing is syntactic sugar for the definition of a module).

Modules get to decide what names (?) they want to export to other modules, and some things about how they want to export them, and also what other modules they rely on and some things about how they rely on them.

Modules can be nested inside other modules, including in the same file.  But the simple case is where each file contains a single module, and that's all I'll even try to deal with.

Modules are introded [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/modules.html) and the reference manual is [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/module.html).

### Defining what names are provided: `provide`

This is done by `provide`.  This is a bit of syntax which says what names get exported from a module: all other definitions in the module are private.

There are lots of complexities with `provide`, but let's say I had some file which defines some notion of 'doing something with a foo'.  It wants to define a function `call-with-foo` and a macro `with-foo` which related to each other in the normal way.  But there's a bunch of other stuff in the file to do with the implementation of `foo`s which is private.  So my file, `"foo.rkt"` might look like this:

```
#lang racket

(provide call-with-foo
         with-foo)

(define (call-with-foo fn)
  ...)

(define-syntax-rule (with-foo (f) form ...)
  (call-with-foo (λ (f) form ...)))

(define (make-foo ...)
  ...)

(define (validate-foo foo)
  ...)

...
```

So this means that any module which wants to use this one only gets to see `call-with-foo` and `with-foo`: all the other definitions are internal.

`provide` can do a lot more than this: for instance it can rename definitions as they get exported.  This is useful if you are redefining basic parts of the language.  For instance if I was defining a language a bit like Racket, but where `define` was different, I might write:

```
#lang racket

(provide (rename-out [new-define define]))

(define-syntax new-define
  ...)

;;; This is Racket's define, not ours
;;;
(define ...)
```

And you can say things like 'export everything' (`all-defined-out`), or 'export everything except ...' (`except-out`) and so on and so on.  There are lots of things you can do.

### Specifying what modules you depend on

So there are two ways a module gets to import names from other modules usually.

The first is via `#lang ...`: something like

```
#lang racket
...
```

is the same, I think, as

```
(module <name> racket ...)
```

Where `<name>` comes from the file name, and this means 'start by using all the name that the `racket` module exports (but be willing to override them)'.  I think there is slightly more than this because you can also get to redefine basic aspects of the syntax of the rest of the file here.  In any case `#lang` tells a module where it should start from.

The other way is by `require`.  This is even hairier than `provide`, because not only does it need to be able to specify things like 'I need only some things from this module' and 'I need things from this module under some different names', it *also* needs to be able to specify what 'this module' means.

The most common case you see for specifying 'thos module' is something like `(require racket/tcp)` which means 'I need the `"tcp"` module from the `"racket"` collection' (and this is secretly the same as `(require (lib "racket/tcp")` which is kind of easier to understand in fact I think), where the whole 'collection' thing is [arcane and complicated](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/collects.html#%28tech._collection%29) in he way software installation systems always are (it's not incomprehensible though, I think).

But for modules you define as part of a program you're writing things are much simpler: you specify 'this module' by (a string representing) the name of its file, which interpreted relative to the module doing the `require`ing.  If I want to import things from the `"foo.rkt"` module above, I just say:

```
(require "foo.rkt")
```

And now I have everything it is willing to give me (everything in its `provide` form or forms).

As with `provide` I can do all sorts of trickery to specify what I want to get, as well as renaming things &c &c.  A simple case which will work with `"foo.rkt"`'s `provide` form is:

```
(require (only-in "foo.rkt" with-foo))
```

Which means 'just give me `with-foo`, I don't care about anything else'.  This is useful because it means you can be very specific about what names you want, and not clutter up your module with junk.

There are lots of other things you can do with `require`.

### Modules and contracts

One very useful thing you can do it to specify contracts at module boundaries.  Contracts are introduced [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts.html?q=contracts) and reference material is [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contracts.html).

Let's say that, for my `"foo.rkt"` module, I know that `call-with-foo` expects a procedure as its argument, and that procedure gets a single argument, and may return anything.  There are two ways to do this: you can define the contract on the function in `"foo.rkt"`:

```
(define/contract (call-with-foo fn)
  (-> (-> any/c any) any))
  ...)
```

Or you can specify the contact at the `provide` level:

```
(provide (contract-out
          (call-with-foo
           (-> (-> any/c any) any)))
         with-foo)
```

These are mostly the same for users of the module.  The first case looks better because the contract will be enforced even within the module.  But the first case, for instance, allows you to enforce contracts at module boundaries which are stricter than contracts within the module, which can be useful.

In any case contracts are a pretty neat tool to find problems early on, and they're particularly useful at module boundaries.

### Big modules

One thing that almost inevitably happens is that your little single-file module eventually gets too big, so you want it to become more than one file.  This is easy to do: you can just make your main module file reprovide things from implementation modules.  So, for instance, `"foo.rkt"` might become:

```
#lang racket

(require "foo/main.rkt")

(provide (all-from-out "foo/main.rkt"))
```

and `"foo/main.rkt"` might in turn be:

```
#lang racket

(require "simple.rkt" "complicated.rkt")

(provide (all-from-out "simple.rkt" "complicated.rkt"))
```

and finally `"foo/simple.rkt"` might have the implementation of part of the now vast module, complete with `provide` forms as appropriate:

```
#lang racket

(provide (contract-out
          (call-with-foo
           (-> (-> any/c any) any))))

(define (call-with-foo fn)
  ...)
```

All of the `(require "x/y.rkt")` looks like it is hopelessly *nix-specific, but in fact it all is platform-agnostic: module specifications aren't really pathnames, they just get translated into them, and that translation happens appropriately for the platform.

(The reason for this `"main.rkt"` thing is that if this ever gets turned into a library, then `(require .../foo)` means 'look for `"main.rkt"` wherever `.../foo` told you to go'.  At least I think so.)

Comment: Thanks! The Big modules section is exactly what I needed.